# Scroll to top and animated scroll to #page link conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop, smooth-scrolling

So, I'm quite new to javascript and building a site where I'm trying to have animated scrolls on the page.

To enable animated scroll to a link I'm using this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

         var target = this.hash,
         $target = $(target);

         $('html, body').stop().animate({
             'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
         }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
})();
```

To scroll to the top of the page I am using this code.

```
//<-- scroll top -->

var $top = jQuery.noConflict();
$top("#scroll-top").hide();

// fade in #scroll-top
$top(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($top(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $top('#scroll-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $top('#scroll-top').fadeOut();
    }
});

// scroll body to 0px on click
$top('#scroll-top a').click(function () {
    $top('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);
    return false;
});
```

They both work fine independently, but not together.
Can anybody help me find out why they conflict, and how to solve the conflict?

Comment: I beleive there is conflict in selectors: `$('a[href^="#"]')` and `$('#scroll-top a')` perhaps are selecting same links and hence the conflict

Comment: provide a working example to figure out the problem.

Comment: Ok, so before I got back here I managed to fix it by doing removing the "// scroll body to 0px on click" section of the code, putting an id at the top of page, and using the animated scroll (the first code block I posted, to scroll both down and up.

As I said I'm new to JS and this is the result of copy pastes and tryouts. The result is here http://julebord.bedriftsdesign.no/julebord.html.
If you'd like to take a look and see if you think the way I solved it is ok I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how I fixed my issue:

I removed the conflicting code  " // scroll body to 0px on click " and instead use the animated scroll to anchor link to animate both functions, with a  placed on top of the page as well.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

         var target = this.hash,
         $target = $(target);

         $('html, body').stop().animate({
             'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
         }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
})();
```

I works fine, but I am missing only one feature, that the javascript recognises internal links that start with anything else than #. Right now it doesn't recognise for example this link http://julebord.bedriftsdesign.no/julebord.html#julemeny. It only works if I use this: #julemeny